# Visa to visit Saudi Arabia from Bahrain for an Indian passport holder

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, saudi-arabia

I am an Indian passport holder working in Bahrain. I want to visit my father in Riyadh. Is there a one week visa available for such a journey to Saudi Arabia? If not, is there any other option? A Transit visa maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Transit visas are not applicable to you (you would need a permanent resident visa in a bordering country (other than Qatar) to apply for a transit visa), there are also no visas on arrival for Saudi Arabia.

Your only option therefore is to apply for a family visit visa (your father can request it on your behalf). Once approved, approach the embassy to have it stamped on your passport.

It will be a single entry visa valid for 90 days.